# How do create an http redirect an http request coming in on port 80 to https on port 443?

Tags: node.js, http

I'd like to create a status 301 redirect from a url like http://whatever.com/whatever?whatever to https://whatever.com/whatever?whatever . I'm using node.js but I doubt the answer is node-specific.

I know you can write the "Location" header with a url like this:

```
response.writeHead(301, {
   'Location': request.url
});
response.end();
```

But how do I specify that i want the redirect to go to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to use a 301 permanent redirect for this purpose. To change protocols, you need to include the protocol and host in the `Location` header:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var newUrl = 'https://' + request.headers.host + request.url;
    response.writeHead(301, {
       'Location': newUrl
    });
    response.end();
});
```

The standard Node HTTP package doesn't automatically parse the hostname and port, so if you need compatibility with nonstandard ports you should use a package like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) to easily grab `req.hostname`.

Comment: Thats it! Just needed a way to get the host. I found it somewhere else, so its pretty trippy to see that you wrote essentially verbatim what i already have in my code. But correct answer so you get the check, thanks!